# bindParam insert into table where

Tags: php, pdo

I have been coding for a few hours on this thing, so I think I am missing something very simple here, but I can't seem to find it.

I am getting these 2 errors

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 77
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 79

```
public function resetPassword($password, $email){
    $rst    =   $this->db->prepare("insert into users (password) values (?) where email=? ");
    $rst->bindParam('?', $password);
    $rst->bindParam('?', $email);
    $rst->execute();
    
    if($rst->execute()){
        return "Password changed!"; 
    }
    else echo "Could not change password.";
}
```

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using questions marks as placeholders, you send an array to the execute method, like so: `$rst->execute(array('placeholder1value', 'placeohlder2value'));`

However, if you want to use named placeholders, you would bindParam/bindValue them, like so:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (key1, key2) VALUES (:key1, :key2)');
$stmt->bindValue(':key1', 'somevalue', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':key1', 3532, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Please read about the difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue`

And another note, your SQL query doesn't make sense, do you mean to do an `UPDATE`?

Comment: Thanks, you were right about both. I used an array, and I changed my query to update.
Still one problem though, I got it to update the password in the database, but now it returns 'Could not change password'.